# Incorrect function for decimal-to-binary conversion?

Tags: java, math, binary, decimal, converters

I am trying to create a method that converts Decimal to Binary. Here is what I wrote so far (which is not working properly):

```
public static String D2B(int decimal){
    String binaryValue="";
    for (int tempDecimal=decimal;0==tempDecimal;tempDecimal/=2){
        binaryValue=tempDecimal%2+binaryValue;
    }
    return binaryValue;
} 


public static void main(String[]args){
    int myValue=127;
    System.out.println(D2B(myValue));
}
```

Comment: There is no decimal here What you are really doing is converting to printable ASCII.

Answer (score 2):

I think the condition in your loop is incorrect:

```
for(int tempDecimal=decimal;0==tempDecimal;tempDecimal/=2)
```

Note that this loops while tempDecimal is equal to 0, which means that the loop should not loop at all for nonzero inputs and will loop forever for zero inputs.  Try rewriting it as

```
for(int tempDecimal = decimal; 0 != tempDecimal; tempDecimal /= 2)
```

Also, watch out for 0 as an input and for negative numbers as inputs; they won't come out correctly with your current approach.

A few other minor nits:

- I strongly suggest indenting your code correctly and putting spaces in-between the operators for readability.  It makes the code much easier to read, and I think you would have spotted the bug more easily had you had more spaces.
- There's no reason to create a second variable `tempDecimal` in this function.  Java parameters are passed by value, so changes you make to the argument won't show up in the caller.  Since you're not using the `decimal` value anywhere else, the extra variable is superfluous.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for advices... I'm new for programing... I don't know much about programing rules.. Now I got that... next time it never happen... Thanks again...